# Doing things (driving servos, turning on led) using joystick input

Tags: python, robotics, joystick, evdev

I'm building a basic DVa Mech robot (hobby).  This is non-bipedal.  Wheeled chassis. All code in python.

How do I continuously perform activities while holding down a button, pushing a joystick?  And can I even do two (or more) at once: move wheels forward, turn torso, fire guns?

I'm reading joystick input fine. Servos work too.
I can't seem to figure out the logic loops of 'while button pushed - do something - and keep scanning for more input'

Tried various things...they didn't work so they are out of the code below.

Running 6 continuous servos (4 for chassis, two for mini-guns)
Logitech F710 joystick

```
from evdev import InputDevice, categorize, ecodes, KeyEvent
from adafruit_servokit import ServoKit
import time
kit = ServoKit(channels = 16)
gamepad = InputDevice('/dev/input/event7')
print (gamepad)
for event in gamepad.read_loop():
    if event.type == ecodes.EV_KEY:
            keyevent = categorize(event)
            if keyevent.keystate == KeyEvent.key_down:
                    print(keyevent)
                    ....
                    elif keyevent.keycode == 'BTN_TL':
                            print ("Guns")
    elif event.type == ecodes.EV_ABS:
            absevent = categorize(event)
            print(absevent.event.code)
            if ecodes.bytype[absevent.event.type][absevent.event.code] == 'ABS_HAT0X':
                    if absevent.event.value == -1:
                            print('left')
                    elif absevent.event.value == 1:
                            print('right')
            if ecodes.bytype[absevent.event.type][absevent.event.code] == 'ABS_HAT0Y':
                    if absevent.event.value == -1:
                            print('forward')
                    elif absevent.event.value == 1:
                            print('back')
```

Fairly basic...when BTN_TL is pressed, servos 5 and 6 should spin until the button is released

Likewise with HAT0X and 0Y the servos should move forward/back/left/right while pressed.

I've tried while loops and whatnot...but there's a logic/timing sequence in joystick input I'm not putting in the right place

Answer (score 0):

For the **servo** part and based on [Servokit documentation](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_CircuitPython_ServoKit) there is two ways to control servos:

1. Set desired shaft angle:

```
    kit.servo[servonum].angle = 180
```

2. Indicate rotation direction (`1`: forward, `-1`: backward, `0`: stop) like:

```
    kit.continuous_servo[servonum].throttle = 1 
    kit.continuous_servo[servonum].throttle = -1
    kit.continuous_servo[servonum].throttle = 0
```

I'd rather use angles, even if I'd have to increment/decrement their values (according to time) in the loop. It would give you a hand on speed (or speed curve) and position.

For the **Joystick** part, the [Eric Goebelbecker](https://ericgoebelbecker.com/2015/07/raspberry-pi-and-gamepad-programming-part-3-adding-a-gun-turret/)'s "tutorial" worth a reading.

EDIT: Solution with `continuous_servo` (for future reading)

`ABS_HAT0{X,Y}` notifies DOWN event with -1 or +1 on the active axis. And UP with 0 value.

```
axis_servo = {
    'ABS_HAT0X': 5,
    'ABS_HAT0Y': 6,
}

[...]
        axis = ecodes.bytype[absevent.event.type][absevent.event.code]
        if axis == 'ABS_HAT0X':
            servonum = axis_servo[axis]
            kit.continuous_servo[servonum].throttle = absevent.event.value
        if axis == 'ABS_HAT0Y':
            servonum = axis_servo[axis]
            # Reverse Y axis (1 -> up direction)
            kit.continuous_servo[servonum].throttle = -absevent.event.value
```

Without `continuous_servo`, one should consider the use of `select()` with **timeout** (`select([gamepad], [], [], timeout)`) as described in [readthedoc: python-evdev](https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#reading-events-from-multiple-devices-using-select).

The timeout will allow angle computation.

Comment: Thank you!  The trouble I'm having with Eric's tutorial is that he uses the EV_SYN event to kick off the activity.  As I understand it, the EV_SYN happens when you release the button.  His code then calculates how long the button was held down and then executes the movement.  I'm looking for press button-move servo immediately and continue to move it until I let go....but I may be misunderstanding his code?